# How to pass parameters to testng.xml file?

Tags: testng

I need to run testng testng Testcases on various  host, version, browser and port ,
For example 192.xxx.xx.10 , ver34,Firefox/IE , 5555 to 5560, here version nothing but a different URL of the application. so i feel better to pass these parameters to start selenium rc.
Is it possible how can i achive this?
Here my expectaion is:

1) select the RC available on machine3 + version 34 + *firefox + 5555
2) select the RC available on machine2 + version 45 + *explore + 4445

with single testNg.xml, I kept my sources on CVS based on the local properties file on every system testNg.xml if react it will be much helper.
Thanks in advance,
Mani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define system properties when launching the JVM (-Dfoo=bar) and TestNG will turn these into parameters, similar to the `<parameters>` used in testng.xml.